# Nested ListView Items - TreeView&ListView combined

Tags: wpf, listview, treeview

The best way to show what I need is showing an image:

[image]

What is the easiest way to implement this kind of "nested ListView" - each Item can be expanded and has subitems. I want the hierarchy only to show on the first column as shown when any other solution can be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to do it. I consider that you are good in WPF and easily check code and take idea from it because it is not easy to give code of your requirement here.

You must need to user [Expander](https://wpftutorial.net/Expander.html) for expand and collapse functionality for the detail sections as per you image.

I am sharing some the links from where you can easily get what you want. It is not exact code which you can copy but it will give you basic structure of what you want.

1. Listview and Expander

[Sample-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45402422/wpf-expander-binding-in-listview)

2. Expander and DataGrid

[Sample-1](http://www.codearsenal.net/2012/08/wpf-expander-with-datagrid.html#.Wmp98XaWZPY)
[Sample-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46139353/wpf-datagrid-nested-in-expander-no-scrolling-datagrid-content)

You will enjoy working on this one.